# Let $f$ be a function with measurable domain $D$. show that$ f$ is mble iff the function $g$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working through some problems in Real Analysis (Royden) and I came across this one.

Let $f$ be a function with  measurable domain $D$. Show that $f$ is measurable if and only if the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,  defined by $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in D$ and $g(x)=0, $ for $x\notin D$, is measurable.

I realized that in one direction, if $g$ is measurable then
$$\{x \in D : f(x)>c\}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}:g(x)>c \}\cap D$$
since  $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in D$.  Because the sets $D$ and $\{x \in \mathbb{R}:g(x)>c \}$ are measurable , $f$ is measurable.

On the other hand if $f$ is measurable, then 
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:g(x)>c\}=
\begin{cases}
\{x\in D:f(x)>c\}, &\mbox{ if }x\in D\\
D^c, &\mbox{ if }x\notin D \mbox{ and } c<0\\
\varnothing, &\mbox{ if }x\notin D \mbox{ and } c\geq0.
\end{cases}
$$
Because $\{x\in D:f(x)>c\}$, $D^c$, and $\varnothing$ are meas sets, it follows that $g$ is measurable.

This illustration is almost clear to me except the part where we consider the cases where $c \ge $ 0 and $c<0$. I don't understand why we do that.
Can someone explain to me or give me a similar one.

Comment: @Summarizing the comments, I edited your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$ If $f$ is meas and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ then

$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:g(x)<\alpha\}=
\begin{cases}
\{x\in D:f(x)<\alpha\}, &\mbox{ if }x\in D\\
D^c, &\mbox{ if }x\notin D \mbox{ and } \alpha >0\\
\varnothing, &\mbox{ if }x\notin D \mbox{ and } \alpha \leq0.
\end{cases}
$$
This shows that $g$ is meas.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose $g$ is meas and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha))=g^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha))\cap D.$$
This shows that $f$ is meas.

Comment: Could it also go this way. 


$$\Rightarrow$$ if $f$ is mble and $\alpha \in R$ then 
$$   g^{-1}((\alpha ,\infty))= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      f^{-1}((\alpha ,\infty)) & \text{if} \quad  x\in D  \\
          D^c & \text{if} \quad x \notin D \quad \text{and} \quad \alpha < 0 \\
        \phi &  \text{if} \quad x\notin D \quad \text{and} \quad\alpha \ge 0          
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$
And that G is measurable?

Comment: Yes, and thank you.

Comment: Your first equation doesn't make sense. The right side refers to a variable $x$ that is not present on the left.

Comment: @mario, what are  the differences between the first  and the edited one, can you explain further? if possible in grammar as well. thanks

Comment: @J.Kyei The edit is the same as the original, and still has the same issue, although it is now harder to see - the $x$ in the if statement cases is not bound, where as the two set comprehensions have an (unrelated) bound variable $x$. I believe the correct equation is: $$g^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha))=\begin{cases}f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha))\cup D^c,&\mbox{if }\alpha>0\\f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha)),&\mbox{if }\alpha\le 0\end{cases}.$$